# ¿Por qué en mi pagina web no me muestra los cambios realizados?

Tags: html, web, hosting

Subí mi página web al hosting, pero al momento de realizar cambios no se actualizaban en la página hasta después de 1 día, imagine que sería un problema de código, probé subiendo un archivo index.html con estructura básica:

```
<html lang="es">
    <head>
    <title>Hi :)</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Hi world!</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Sin embargo, sigo teniendo el mismo problema, también borro el caché y utilizo una página en incognito pero aún así no se muestran los cambios, pero sí lo visualizo desde otro dispositivo o en la versión móvil del inspeccionador de la página sí se muestran los cambios realizados.

El siguiente detalle es este, la página que voy a subir tendrá constantes actualizaciones y necesito que los cambios se muestren en tiempo real sin necesidad de borrar caché o esperar 1 día, que sería demasiado para el cliente.

Por lo tanto me gustaría saber cuál es el problema que lo está ocasionando y cómo podría solucionarlo.

[image: Código modificado]

[image: La versión que me muestra en el ordenador]

[image: Verión movil del]

Comment: Revisa que apps tiene el servidor, hay servidores que agregan su propio sistema de Caché para mejorar las velocidades, un ejemplo es Cloudways que agrega el systema Vanish, el cual debe ser desactivado si no quieres estar borrando constantemente el cache del servidor.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda! Gracias a ello pude encontrar lo que estaba guardando el caché en el servidor y ya lo pude solucionar. Muchas gracias!